# PHP account privilege , session or mysql check

Tags: php

For a user with moderator privileges; When the user logs in do i query to check the user is a moderator, then set a session?  So on pages with moderator options , for example

```
if($_SESSION['mod']==1) {
//moderator options
}
```

Alternatively do i put a query on everypage and check if the user is flagged as a moderator? Then for moderator options, for example

```
if($moderatorfound==1) {
//moderator options
}
```

Below, I currently set the username as a moderator in a cookie but as i am learning about PHP security this is unsafe;

```
    if($moderator=='1') {
    setcookie('username[3]',$moderator,time()+(60*60*24*365));  
    }

 if($_COOKIE['username'][3]==1) {
    //moderator options
    }
```

What is the secure way to do this? Example would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the user logs in, store his information in session variables.
No need to check with the database on every page.
A cookie is not a good solution to hold sensitive information (such as privileges), since it might be altered by the user.

Comment: so i would just do $_SESSION['moderator']=1; when logged in? Is that secure enough?

Comment: it depends by what you mean in "enough", but yes - generally it suffices.

Answer (score 0):

In the cookie, set a complex code and save that in a database. If the complex code matches that of the username allow access.